# Windows 10 corrupt boot sector - system will not boot

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk, diskpart

After replacing an SSD that failed to boot properly, I still have trouble.

The new SSD is a Samsung EVO 860 500GB, running Win10 64.

On booting, the error is:
`reboot and select proper boot device`
I have tried to repair the boot sector with testdisk (edited).

Afterward,

I get a NTFS file system blue screen.

Attempting to boot from a rescue CD also gives the blue screen error.
Even attempting to boot from the SSD via a USB-to-SATA adapter results in the blue screen error.

How can I boot to a command line prompt to run a disk check program?
How can I repair or access the SSD ?

Comment: "I tried to repair the bootsector with diskpart." - What did you do exactly?  Please edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: Sounds like the SSD is irreparable, time for a new one or send it in under warranty.

Comment: before you do anything else, replace the SATA cable.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote something wrong. diskpart wasn't possible, because my recue USb has no command-shell. i meant testdisk. SATA cable is already replaced

Comment: Hi Rene1981, and welcome. I've been asked to review your first question, and I've made some edits to be in line with this site's guidelines. Please look over the changes and review the posting guidelines within StackExchange. Again, welcome!

Comment: More constructive comments: The community will need more and more precise detail on what you have tried and what you are observing. While it takes great effort to copy down an error precisely, those errors help experts understand what you are facing, and what you have tried. From your info, it appears you have a hardware problem (if you cannot boot to a rescue CD), but this would be somewhat unusual.

Comment: @Rene1981 - You need to edit and clarify your question.  At this point you are the only user who can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to isolate the failure by trying approaches that are known (or highly likely) to work. This assumes you have access to a working computer.

0. disconnect the failing SSD
1. Verify your computer boots by creating a Linux boot USB. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
2. Attempt to boot from the Linux boot USB. You may have to choose the boot device. This process is specific to your computer, so watch the initial boot screens carefully (often pressing F2, F11, or F12 to "select boot device").
3. Assuming the computer completes the Linux booting process, you can choose to a) use the working Linux system to test, troubleshoot, and repair your SSD, or you can attempt to boot. Edit this original question with your progress.
4. connect the failing SSD, preferably using a docking station or external adapter to ensure proper power supply